# Finding size of array of structs C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, size

I am trying to find the size of the struct array that I am using to do a sort on it. Not sure how to implement it with the sizeof() function that is normally used in nonstruct arrays.

I am also trying to figure what I am doing wrong when initializing the vehicle struct in the arguments vs the temp struct variable.

```
error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘struct data *’ using type ‘struct data’
struct data *temp = vehicles[j];
```

This is the data struct that I am using

```
struct data{

    char *model;
    float engineSize;
    int cost;
    char *color;
};
```

This is the code that I am currently running for the sort that I am using

```
    void bubbleSortFloats(struct data vehicles[], int check)
    {
       int i, j, n;

       n = sizeof(vehicles)/sizeof(vehicles[0]);

      // If check == 1 then ascending sort
      if(check == 1){

       for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){     

           // Last i elements are already in place   
           for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){


               if (vehicles[j].engineSize > vehicles[j+1].engineSize){

                    struct data temp = vehicles[j];
                    vehicles[j] = vehicles[j+1];
                    vehicles[j+1] = temp; 

               }
            }
        }
      }
      // If check == 0 then decending sort
      if(check == 0){

        for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){     

           // Last i elements are already in place   
           for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){


               if (vehicles[j].engineSize < vehicles[j+1].engineSize){

                    struct data temp = vehicles[j+1];
                    vehicles[j+1] = vehicles[j];
                    vehicles[j] = temp; 

               }
            }
        }
      }

    }
```

This is the update with the readfile function that I am using

```
struct values * readFile(){

    FILE *fp;
    int c;
    int count = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    fp = fopen("hw3.data", "r");


    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        if(c == '\n'){
            count++;
        }

    }

    if (feof(fp)){

        rewind(fp);

        struct data *vehicles = malloc((sizeof(struct data))* count);


        count = 0;
        char *token = NULL;
        while (getline(&line, &len, fp)!= -1){

            printf("%s", line);

            token = strtok(line,  " ");

            vehicles[count].model = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
            strcpy(vehicles[count].model, token);

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            vehicles[count].engineSize = atof(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            vehicles[count].cost = atoi(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            vehicles[count].color = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
            strcpy(vehicles[count].color, token);

            free(line);
            line = NULL;
            len = 0;

        }
        struct values *value = malloc(sizeof(struct values));
    value.vehicles = vehicles;
    value.count = count;
    return value;
    }
```

Comment: regarding: `if (feof(fp)){`  NEVER use the function: `feof()` as a loop control.  It does not do what you seem to think it does.  In the posted code, the `if()` statement can be  removed.

Comment: this code block: `while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        if(c == '\n'){
            count++;
        }` is not dependable because a text file does not necessarily have a terminating newline sequence on the last line

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: ( malloc, calloc, realloc ): always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code

```
sizeof(vehicles)/sizeof(vehicles[0]);
```

will only work with **true** arrays.

In

```
void bubbleSortFloats(struct data vehicles[], int check);
```

`vehicles` look like an array but in fact it is a pointer, this function
definition is the same as

```
void bubbleSortFloats(struct data *vehicles, int check);
```

In C you cannot pass true arrays to the functions, they always are passed as
pointers. Even with code like this:

```
void foo(int arr[10])
{
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof arr / sizeof *arr);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = { 0 };
    foo(arr);
}
```

I get a warning of my compiler:

```
a.c: In function ‘foo’:
a.c:6:25: warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘arr’ will return size of ‘int *’ [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
  printf("%lu\n", sizeof arr);
                         ^~~
a.c:4:14: note: declared here
 void foo(int arr[10])
              ^~~
```

and if I execute it, I get 2, because on my system the size of a pointer is 8
and the size of an `int` is 2. That's why the `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` doesn't
work in a function that gets an array passed.

You have to calculate the length of the array **before** you call
`bubbleSortFloats` and pass that length to the function. The correct function
would be:

```
void bubbleSortFloats(struct data *vehicles, size_t len, int check)
{
    ...
}
```

We don't see how you created the array, but the function that creates it will
know the size:

```
void foo(void)
{
    struct data vehicles[SOME_LEN];
    ...

    bubbleSortFloats(vehicles, sizeof vehicles / sizeof *vehicles, check);
}
```

or if you did it with `malloc`

```
void foo(void)
{
    size_t len = ...;

    struct data *vehicles = malloc(len * sizeof *vehicles);
    if(vehicles == NULL)
        return;

    ...

    bubbleSortFloats(vehicles, len, check);
}
```

---

**edit**

> *Jeffrey Hennen asked in the comment section*:
>
> I made it clear. I am going to want to return a structure and an int count for the size of the array of structures

Like I said in the comments, if you want to return more than one value, you have
essentially two options:

1. Declare a struct that encapsulates all the returning values and return it
2. Or pass pointers to the function and let the function update the values
   provided by the pointers.

You've chosen way 1, so I guess you have this struct:

```
struct values {
    struct data *vehicles;
    size_t count;
};
```

Then the way you are returning it, is OK. Of course you should check that the
last `malloc` did not return `NULL` (you are ignoring that throughout the whole
function, though).

The second option would be:

The easiest way would be:

```
struct data *readFile(size_t *length) {
    if(length == NULL)
        return NULL;

    ...
    while (getline(&line, &len, fp)!= -1){
        ...
    };

    // NOT NEEDED ANYMORE
    //struct values *value = malloc(sizeof(struct values));
    //value.vehicles = vehicles;
    //value.count = count;

    *length = count; // UPDATE the length through the pointer
    return vehicles; // return the array
}
```

and the calling function would do:

```
void foo(void)
{
    size_t count;
    struct data *vehicles = readFile(&count);
    if(vehicles == NULL)
    {
        // error
        return;
    }

    do_something_with_the_vehicles(vehicles, count);

    free_the_vehicles(vehicles, count);
}
```

Of course you would have to write a function `free_the_vehicles` (you can of
course choose another name) that frees all the memory allocated.

Comment: I just put my code in for the read file and how would i go about making the code actually return both the array that I created when reading the file and then also return the count of the file so i can use this count value for print along with the sorts

Comment: @JeffreyHennen if you want to return more than one value, you have to options: declare a struct with member that represent the values you want to return and the function should return the struct. Or your function can expect a pointer to the values you want to return and write the values through the provided pointers.

Comment: @JeffreyHennen if your question does not have anything to do with your current one (getting size of array), I suggest that you create a new question for that. The comment section is very limiting for precise answers.

Comment: sorry I don't think I made it clear. I am going to want to return a structure and an int count for the size of the array of structures

Comment: @JeffreyHennen Like I said, create a new question with your new question, it's much easier for us to deal with new questions than with new questions in the comments. For this one time, I'll made an update of my answer addressing your second question, but in the feature please ask different questions in different threads. Stack Overflow was not design to handle multiple questions per thread because threads will get long and confusing for readers in the feature.

Comment: @JeffreyHennen I've made the update of my answer. So please for the feature, create new questions for new questions. You see for yourself how long this thread has become.

Comment: The issue with the code you placed corresponding to this is that I am trying to have all my code start with its calls in the main function but I can't have it done that way with the code you are presenting. I also cant have the main have the reading of the file within the main.

Comment: @JeffreyHennen sorry, you've lost me, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: main is only supposed to be used for the menus and calls for the readfile then calls of the print function for the array of structures, call for function of the sorts

Comment: @JeffreyHennen so? where is the problem then? You can always wrap your functions in other functions so that `main` is as little as possible. All the code that I've presented to you doesn't have to be called from `main`. That's why I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean yes I can do it that way, but that is not the way I am trying to implement it.

Comment: @JeffreyHennen Once again, I suggest that you create a new question, where you explain what you goal is, what you already have and where you are having the problem. This new question of yours does not have anything to do with the first question of the thread, so this is getting too long and quite frankly, I don't understand what you really want.

Comment: The reason why I am not trying to implement it that way is that every time the person that is using the menu. They are going to have to read the whole file, again and again, each time they choose an option. The way I am trying to run it, you would only be reading the file once and getting the input from the file and then you would just have to run the operations for sort, print and so on after the fact. But anyways thanks for the help

Comment: @JeffreyHennen I don't know how many times I have to repeat this, but the question you are asking is *how to create a good menu code in the `main` function*. This would be far better in a **new question** where we deal with this. An easy solution would be to have `struct data *vehicles = NULL` in main, when the user enters something, check if the variable is `NULL`. If it is `NULL` then run `vehicles = readFile(&count)`. If the variable is not `NULL`, then don't execute that part. Like I said, this is completely different question from the one above.

Comment: @JeffreyHennen if you want, we can have a little conversion about this in the [chat].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164905/discussion-between-pablo-and-jeffrey-hennen).

Answer (score 0):

```
 struct data *temp = &vehicles[j];
```

Otherwise it is incompatible as you try to assign the pointer with the structure. You need to assign the address of the structure

Answer (score 0):

When copying a struct,  a direct assignment does not work.

Suggest using the function: `memcpy()`.

```
memcpy( temp, &vehicles[j], sizeof( struct data );
```

similar considerations exist for all the statements that are trying to copy the 'struct data' instances